# .NET5 self-contained webAPI with HTTPS

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net5

What would be the best way to allow only HTTPS connections with a self hosted .NET5 webApi?
And how do I go about configuring an SSL Certificate (either real or self-signed)?

I've only used IIS deployments so I'm struggling to understand how to make a webserver I don't control use a specific certificate..

Comment: What server are you hosting on? You can read this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: Yeah that's what I was looking for.
And it seems like it's enough to install the certificate on Windows without a need to select it in ASP.NET like you would in IIS